# How to get the general formula for the following recursion?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The problem is extracted from one part of the problem 12299 of American Mathematical Monthly:

Given a sequence $\left\{x_k\right\}$ with $x_0=x_1=1$ and for integers $k$ with $2\leq k\leq n-1,$ let $x_k=\frac{1}{k}\left(nx_{k-1}-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j\right).$

According to the solution by Roberto Tauraso ([https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~tauraso/AMM/AMM12299.pdf](https://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Etauraso/AMM/AMM12299.pdf)), the general formula can be explicitly given for $k\geq 1,$ $$x_k=\frac{1}{k!}\left(n^{k-1}-\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}(k-1-j)j!n^{k-2-j}\right).$$

However, this general formula is too hard to guess so that we could prove it by induction. Does anyone have some clue on how to guess this sort of general formula or some explicit way to derive it?

Comment: Something has to be wrong with the proposed explicit formula: it can't not depend on the value $x_0 = x_1$. I also think the index $n$ in $\{ x_n \}$ is serving a different purpose than the index $k$ when defining $x_k$.

Comment: The linked PDF doesn't have either of those problems: $x_0 = x_1 = 1$ and the $n$ is separate from $k$.

Comment: (Also, the author of the linked PDF is an active user of this site: [@RobertZ](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299698/robert-z))

Comment: @prets  Thanks for your comment and the error has now been fixed. I don't think there is something to do with another index n in {x_{k,n}} since the "n" here is totally fixed throughout the argument.

Comment: Sure that's fine, but since $n$ is fixed, the sequence you're interested in really isn't $\{ x_n \}$?

Comment: I change {x_n} to {x_k}, thanks!

Comment: Your first sequence should be for $2\le k\le n$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start.

Whenever a recurrence has
$\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j
$,
the summation can usually
be eliminated
while increasing the
order of the recurrence.
Here's how this is done
in this case.

If
$x_k
=\frac{1}{k}\left(nx_{k-1}-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j\right).
$
then
$kx_k
=nx_{k-1}-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j
$
so
$\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j
=nx_{k-1}-kx_k
$
and
$\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j
=nx_{k}-(k+1)x_{k+1}
$

so

$\begin{array}\\
x_k
&=\sum_{j=1}^{k}x_j-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}x_j\\
&=nx_{k}-(k+1)x_{k+1}-(nx_{k-1}-kx_k)\\
&=(n+k)x_{k}-(k+1)x_{k+1}-nx_{k-1}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$(k+1)x_{k+1}
=(n+k-1)x_{k}-nx_{k-1}
$.

I'll leave it at this.